# Seaborn Clustermap: Plot all parameters but only cluster based on some

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, seaborn

I have a dataset that consists of elements with k properties, and I want to be able to hierarchically cluster them based on only some of those properties, but I want to graph a heatmap + dendrogram that contains all of the properties. I am using `seaborn.clustermap` ([link](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html)) to handle the clustering and plotting.

My dataset looks like this:

```
| ID | Property A | Property B | ... | Property k |
| AA |    val1    |    val2    | ... |   valk     |
| AB |    val1    |    val2    | ... |   valk     |
etc.
```

It is straightforward to create an array of k-tuples and pass them into Seaborn for clustering, but only the values that are passed are plotted. How can I plot all values (the output would have a column for each property), but make Seaborn only compute the clusters based on, for instance, Property A and Property B?

My code is straightforward and somewhat irrelevant at this point:

```
# Generate the datamatrix
data = np.array(dataMatrix)
frame = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns = markerHeaders, index = headers)
g = sns.clustermap(frame, metric="euclidean", figsize=(30, 20), cmap=sns.diverging_palette(10, 220, sep=80, as_cmap=True), row_colors = tuple(colors))
g.savefig(clusterForm + ".png")
```